# Read selected columns using fstream

Tags: c++, file, input, fstream

I am using the following codes to read my data from a file, but my issue is that I only want to catch some columns out of many more columns in the file. Is there any better way of doing this than the approach I am using.

```
void Data::read_simulated (const string &filepath)
{
    ifstream data_out (filepath.c_str());

    if (!data_out)
        cout<<"Failed to open"<<endl;
    else
    {
        string id_p,age_p, dim_p, my_p, mcf_p, mcp_p, mcl_p, bw_p, bcs_p;
        string dummy_line, g;
        getline(data_out, dummy_line);

        while(data_out>>age_p>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>bcs_p>>g>>g>>my_p>>g>>g>>bw_p>>g>>g>>dim_p>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g>>g)
        {
            //s.cow_id.push_back(get_number(id_p));
            if (get_number(age_p)>=1424.0 &&get_number(age_p)<=1733.0)
            {
                age_pre.push_back(age_p);
                dim_pre.push_back(dim_p);
                my_pre.push_back(my_p);
                //mcf_obs.push_back(get_number(mcf_p));
                // mcp_obs.push_back(get_number(mcp_p));
                //mcl_obs.push_back(get_number(mcl_p));
                bw_pre.push_back(bw_p);
                bcs_pre.push_back(bcs_p);
            }
        }

        data_out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are aligned with spaces, each starting on a position in line being multiple of a column number and a constant, you could use [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) or [`std::istream::seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) functions to skip some rows.

If that's not the case, at least make your code prettier by using this function:

```
std::istream &skip_row(std::istream &is, unsigned int count)
{
    std::string s;

    while(count-- && is >> s) {}

    return is;
}
```

You could make it a template to accept various types, or you could overload an `operator>>` for a class to get a different syntax than this:

```
data_out >> age_p && skip_row(data_out, 5) && data_out >> bcs_p >> ...
```

A naive approach is to read all rows into a `std::vector<std::string>` and then index it, but it will have an impact on performance due to excessive memory allocation.

Comment: When we add this function to a current class "Data". Do we have to declare Data:: as other normal functions, and how about function prototype in Data.h. I tried to use function skip_row you suggested but it did not work. Error: undefined reference to `Data::skip_row(std::istream&, unsigned int)'|

Comment: @hieu It does not have to be declared in the header and your declaration does not match the definition - missing `&` in the return type. Remove your "answer" if this works, please, that should've been an edit to your question.